# Is there any way to rewrite this to plain JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i wrote some code, that queries through every table and returns text value of cells in arrays. I've also been trying to come up with solution, which won't need jquery. Is there any way to do so?

```
    $(".my-table").each(function (table) {
    $(".my-table tr").each((x) => {
      eachTableXCells = $(this).find(".xcell").toArray();
      tableXCellsData = eachTableXCells.map((x) => x.textContent);

      eachTableYCells = $(this).find(".ycell").toArray();
      tableYCellsData = eachTableYCells.map((y) =>
        parseFloat(y.textContent.replace(",", "."))
      );
    });
    xs.push(tableXCellsData);
    ys.push(tableYCellsData);
    });
    console.log(xs);
    return { xs, ys };
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? A literal answer to your question is "yes" because jquery is implemented in javascript, it _must_ be possible to do it without jquery. That said, this strikes me as exactly the kind of thing jquery is well-suited to. The "vanilla" js version of this is going to be a fair bit more verbose most likely.

Comment: Start here: https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: I've tried to use some multiple queries like 
document.querySelector().querySelectorAll(), but that didn't work

Comment: You've essentially only using 3 jquery methods, and they're [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) (nodeList version) and [querySelector](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#find_children)  Here's a simplified example: https://jsfiddle.net/aof7ct42/

Comment: i know, but that doesn't answer my question in any case

Comment: People on SO tend to like to *fix* your issue, rather than do it for you.   As you *have* made an attempt, include that attempt and you'll more likely get an answer.  Including related, working HTML (just enough) will also help so people don't need to recreate the HTML

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code isn't broken. "Change working jQuery into working JavaScript isn't debugging it's refactoring.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the table you want to target and pass it to a function that handles the work.

Inside the function, call [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on that table to find the target cells. The prototype for [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) supports [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (what `querySelectorAll` returns) but doesn't support [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In order to use map, we have to convert it into an array.

The quickest way to do that is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) then we can use `map()`. Inside the map function, you can do whatever work you want to both the `x` and `y` cells.

Once you're done, return the data for both `x` and `y` in an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

You can then call the function and pass it a table whenever you want to get its data like `getData(MY_TABLE)` and it will return the data.

```js
// function
const getData = (table) => {
  const xCells = [...table.querySelectorAll(".xcell")];
  const xData = xCells.map((xCell) => xCell.textContent);

  const yCells = [...table.querySelectorAll(".ycell")];
  const yData = yCells.map((yCell) =>
    parseFloat(yCell.textContent.replace(",", "."))
  );

  return {
    xData,
    yData
  };
};

// usage
const table = document.querySelector(".my-table-a");
const tableData = getData(table);

const tableTwo = document.querySelector(".my-table-b");
const tableTwoData = getData(tableTwo);

// console logs
console.log({
  tableData
});
console.log({
  tableTwoData
});
```

```html
<table class="my-table-a">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 1</td>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 2</td>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 3</td>
      <td class="ycell">4,2</td>
      <td class="ycell">5,1</td>
      <td class="ycell">6,5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="my-table-b">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 4</td>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 5</td>
      <td class="xcell">xcell 6</td>
      <td class="ycell">7,1</td>
      <td class="ycell">4,7</td>
      <td class="ycell">8,3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't encourage low quality questions that don't show the slightest research effort, by answering.

Comment: wdym? Did i really have to throw these garbage not working pieces of code that i made during my research? I thought it would be easier for all of us if i just write the initial piece of code